# MySql select multiple column unique row

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a small difficulty with writing a query:

I have following table:

```
ID   |   FromId   |  ToId
--------------------------
1         10          15
2         10          15
3         15          10
4         15          10
5         15          20
6         14          15
7         20          15
8         20          10
9         10          20
10        10           1
```

No i would like to get from here unique wich has value of 10

And by unique i mean for example, the result which i would like to accomplish, if the variable is 10

```
FromId   |   ToId
------------------
10            15
20            10
10             1
```

I'm ofcourse not sure if it is possible to accomplish something like that tho ...

For me in this case

```
10   20 == 20   10
```

But for sql not :/

I think ppl dont understand me completly...

I need uniqueness in the combination with 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
select least(fromId, toId) as fromId, greatest(fromId, toId) as toId
from MyTable t
where fromId = 10 or toId = 10
group by least(fromId, toId), greatest(fromId, toId);
```

EDIT:

(In response to your question about performance.)

You should have indexes on `fromId` and `toId`.

Your original data has duplicate values, so the duplicates have to be removed.  In MySQL, this requires sorting the data, either through an explicit `order by` or by using `group by` (and the associated filesort).  The above query should perform as well as any query that uses `distinct`.

If you have two indexes, on `t(fromId, toId)` and `t(toId, fromId)` then the following *might* perform better:

```
select distinct fromId, toId
from MyTable t
where fromId = 10
union all
select distinct fromId, toId
from MyTable t
where toId = 10 and
      not exists (select 1 from MyTable t2 where t2.fromId = t.fromId and t2.toId = t.fromId);
```

MySQL can perform the `distinct` by scanning the index.  I'm not sure if it does in practice.

Comment: I can't help it. I just don't like the look of it.

Comment: what is this with the least and greatest?

Comment: @Alnedru . . . You want to return a single row for each pair of values.  Those functions with the aggregation are used to remove duplicates.

Comment: Very strange that someone would downvote a correct answer without a comment.

Comment: but i'm curious, how performant is this on a large scale table, i mean imaging few million of records ...

Comment: yes, i do have indexes on both as they are FK's, ill check it

Comment: @Alnedru . . . For the last solution, you need two composite indexes on the table.

Comment: btw i dont fully understand, why you have t, then t t and then t2 and t1, i only have one table

Comment: @Alnedru . . . Those are table aliases and needed in this situation to distinguish between references to the same table that is referred to more than one time.

Comment: so if a real name of the table is MyTable then i just should replace t by MyTable

Comment: oh strange don't know why but it misses ToId

Comment: With that other approach i got correct result but with the new approach, i only get FromId which are equal to 10 and don't know why the ToId is not included :(

Comment: However if i'm still gonna use this first approach with least and greatest and on a huge table can it cause issues?

Comment: @Alnedru . . . No issue performance-wise with `least()` and `greatest()`.  The performance will be driven by the `group by`, which  the second method *might* solve.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work,

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FromId = 10 OR ToId = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FromId,ToId FROM myTable  WHERE FromId = 10 OR ToId = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Distinct with OR.

```
select distinct FromId,ToId from Test where FromId = 10 OR ToId=10;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18384/3